# What's the karmic cause for homosexuality?

Tags: karma, sexuality, past-lives

Is being homosexual a result of poor karma? Or is it because of the person's habit in his/her past life? Or perhaps it's because the person likes and supports same-sex couple in his/her past life?

Comment: I didn't know there's already a question related to this, thank you!

Comment: Just put the relevant keywords in the search bar, and you'll see related questions. Also, as you type your question the server will list possible related questions. ;-)